# Android: How to add multiple of the same fragment using a loop

Tags: java, android, loops, android-fragments

I am fairly new to android development, and I'm trying to make a small app that lists names with a few action buttons placed beside each name. My plan was to loop through the list of names, and add a fragment for each one, forming a list of them on the screen.

Right now I was trying to test out the following code. I want to add the fragment "fragTest", to "fragPlaceHolder" in the activity.

This is what my code looks like:

```
//Begin the transaction
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

//Replace the contents of the container with the new fragmentTest
for (int i = 0; i < listLength; i++){
      ft.add(R.id.fragPlaceHolder, new fragmentTest());
}

//Complete the changes
ft.commit();
```

However when I do this, only one fragment ever seems to be added. And if it did work, how would I pass a name as an argument?

Comment: You'll only ever see one Fragment at a time, so why do you want to do this?

Comment: That is what I am asking, how do I see more than one, or is there a better way to do this? like should I add them to a listView?

Comment: Entirely depends what you want to do. A list of names with some buttons? Sounds like you want a ListView for sure, though

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use fragmentTransaction.AddToBackStack(null) in your code.

You can send data to fragment with intent:

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", "From Activity");
//set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj=new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

Recieve data in fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      String strtext=getArguments().getString("message");

return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: ok... where do I add fragmentTransaction.AddToBackStack(null)?

Comment: Add it to your loop.

Comment: it still seems to only add one

Comment: Sure you can only see one as all fragment just can't show in once.  They are all at the back stack.

Comment: nvm, I just had the fragment set to match_parent, so the first one (or second) was just taking up the entire screen. Thanks a bunch!